# Assigning a picture to a new Outlook contact via Applescript

Tags: outlook, applescript

How would I go about assigning a picture to a new Outlook contact in Applescript? The Outlook dictionary tells me that Outlook does have an image class, but I have no clue how to populate one. It doesn't seem to like just being given what the finder thinks is a Jpeg file:

```
tell application "Finder"              
    set theImageFile to a reference to file "Macintosh HD:Users:maximiliantyrtania:Pictures:image-151718-galleryV9-zhek.jpg"
    --set theImageFilePosixPath to POSIX file "/Users/maximiliantyrtania/Pictures/image-151718-galleryV9-zhek.jpg"
    set filekind to (kind of theImageFile) as string
    display dialog "its a" & filekind--displays "its a jpeg"
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    make new contact with properties {first name:"some", last name:"one", image:theImageFile, email addresses:{{address:"work@mywork.com", type:work}, {address:"home@myhome.com", type:home}}}
end tell
```

Result: `error "„«class docf» \"image-151718-galleryV9-zhek.jpg\" of «class cfol» \"Pictures\" of «class cfol» \"maximiliantyrtania\" of «class cfol» \"Users\" of «class sdsk» of application \"Finder\"“ kann nicht in den erwarteten Typ umgewandelt werden." number -1700 from «class docf» "image-151718-galleryV9-zhek.jpg" of «class cfol» "Pictures" of «class cfol» "maximiliantyrtania" of «class cfol» "Users" of «class sdsk»`

I guess I have to say something along the lines of:
set theImageToAssign to make new image () , but what might the syntax be? Can't find anything about that on the net.

Comment: One thing I notice is that in the definition for "load image" in the Outlook dictionary, the comment says "image: NSData of the image to use for this contact. When I actually try to get the value of an existing image in a contact, I see «data imgr followed by an encoded image of some kind. But I do not know whether an NSData representation of the image would work, or how to get that - a command line utility? coding in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the image bytes directly, and then pass them in after the contact is created.

```
set theImageFile to a reference to POSIX file "/Users/maximiliantyrtania/Pictures/image-151718-galleryV9-zhek.jpg"

set img_file to open for access theImageFile
set img_data to read img_file as "JPEG"

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set new_contact to make new contact with properties {first name:"Joan", last name:"Smith", email addresses:{{address:"work@mywork.com", type:work}, {address:"home@myhome.com", type:home}}}        
    set the image of new_contact to img_data        
end tell
```

Would be good practice trap the above image reading stuff for errors too.